# Rails Associations and Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning scopes in Rails and having some trouble making some scope definitions. Say I have the following models..

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, :through => :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :categories, :through => :post
  # attribute: owner
end
```

Notice the attribute owner for Comment. I'm trying to write a scope which will return me the categories that have comments made by only the owner I pass. So if a category has comments and these comments are made by several other owners, these should not be included. I have this working somewhat. I'm getting categories that have comments with the owner I pass..but I also get categories that have comments by other owners too.

In my Category model, I have this..

```
scope :comments_by_owner, lambda { |name| joins(:comments).where("comments.owner = ?", name) }
```

I make a call using

```
Category.comments_by_owner("tom")
```

I tried playing around with joins and uniq but no luck..

Comment: So you want Categories that only contain comments by a specified owner?

Comment: Yes @Fred that's right. Sorry I didn't see your comment until now.

Comment: I can see how to do it using Array#select on arel's arrays, but I'm not quite certain how to override ActiveRecord's select, so I'm reluctant to give code. Basically, I'd iterate through the Category records, and for each one, run the comments, rejecting the category if I found a comment that had comment.name != name. Whatever's left are your single commentor categories.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scope :comments_by_owner, lambda { |name| joins(:posts => :comments).where(:comments => {:owner => name})
```

Comment: It get's the same result as what I have. It's giving me categories that have comments with owner = params[:name] and owner = other people too

Comment: Is :owner simply a string attribute of Category?

Comment: No, owner is not in Category, it's a string attribute of comment

Comment: Sorry - I meant Comment. (I was checking that it was a string as opposed being a separate model, which is more typical for case like yours.) Do you happen to have any default scopes defined on Category that may be overriding comments_by_owner?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `select` with a block uses `Array#select`. Try running through all categories, selecting categories which contain no comments for other names.

```
def find_single_name_categories(name)
  Category.scoped.select do |category|
    category.comments.scoped.select { |comment| comment.name != name }.empty?
  end
end
```